# How to make objects in unity fall smoother

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

In my game there are objects that fall from them sky and i have noticed that they do not fall smoothly when i add the rigidbody2d to them. I have tried interpolation , Lerps, Smoothdamp and still it doesn’t fall smoothly. How can i make it fall smoothly again?

Comment: The object is lagging, right ?. Consider your camera

Comment: How many objects are falling at the same time? How many FPS are you getting in your Editor? How many objects are there in your scene?

Comment: @JustARandomWibuuuu what should i do to the camera?

Comment: There are about 5 objects falling at the same time. and there are 2 objects in my scene but i have a monster and a coin powerup spawn after every 2 seconds